# dynamic content without databse - jquery load and seo

Tags: jquery, html

I startin' to make a "static" site without any database. I can't figure out, witch is the best solution for me:

For example i have a main menu with submenus:

1. Our products

   - p1
   - p2
   - p3

So what do you think:

- Should i make a new html file for every submenus
- Or make a product.html (as a container) and make external htmls for the P1, P2, P3 and you some js to load them into product.html? (like jquery load)

I think the 2nd solution is much more elegant, and much less html query but what about the SEO side of this solution?

- may i insert the external htmls in my sitemap.xml so Google will index my site with many many sub pages? Or should i exclude from indexing them?

Thank you for any suggestion and any other way like jquery load.

Thanks

Comment: Is using PHP (or similar) not an option? It's super easy to do `include`s with PHP and it's SEO friendly as well as accessible.

Comment: could you link an example? if include external html to my product.php than every time user hit the submenus need to reload the page? So in this case its not matter to make a new page to every submens. (p1.html, p2.html..etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using PHP (or similar). With it you can easily structure your code like this:

**index.php**

```
<?php include 'header.php' ?>
<?php include 'menu.php' ?>
Unique code for the index-page here
<?php include 'footer.php' ?>
```

**product.php**

```
<?php include 'header.php' ?>
<?php include 'menu.php' ?>
Unique code for the product-page here
<?php include 'footer.php' ?>
```

Etc.

Doing this with JS is bad for several reasons including SEO and accessibility.

Comment: What is the different if i include (with php) the unique part of my site or i make a full site for submenus?

Comment: And what do you think about this: http://www.malbecmedia.com/blog/development/coding-a-ajax-site-that-degrades-gracefully-with-jquery/

Comment: Not sure I get your first question. But the benefit with this (and what I thought you were looking for in your initial post) was that you don't have to duplicate the header/navigation/footer-code on every page. Regarding the link; if it's done properly then fully ajax-driven pages _do_ work fine without JS and are accessible to search engines.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit off topic. But I landed here looking for a solution to have header and footer embedded in the HTML page, so that I don't have to use frontend jQuery to load them, therefore I won't run into the SEO issue.

Here's the solution that I found http://blog.parkji.co.uk/2013/07/06/building-a-static-site-using-grunt-and-assemble.html

Basically, the engine needs to be backend or semi-backend (supporting HTML at least), and before the page load, either the page has already been assembled (like PHP etc.) or it has been manually assembled before deployment (like gruntJS).

Google might be doing some fancy now so that the search engine can understand javascript, but i felt this is a long way to go. Meantime, we can rely on tools that make it happen before the page is delivered to the browser.